# Is it possible for people to live in the eye of a permanent hypercane?

Tags: climate, weather

Wikipedia lists a potential for a hypercane which can have an eye of up to 190 miles in diameter **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercane**

Say there's an earthlike planet that for whatever reason has a permanent hypercane in one of its oceans (kind of like the big red spot on jupiter). This hypercane is in a fixed location and doesn't move. Also say there happens to be an island in the very center of the eye that's roughly circular and about 100 miles in diameter (leaving 45 miles from any shore to the wall of the hypercane).

I'm not interested in talking about whether a storm like this would be possible. I'm interested to know whether this island would be capable of sustaining human life for a long period of time - say hundreds or thousands of years. If not, what things are preventing that from happening?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94384/discussion-on-question-by-rick-d-is-it-possible-for-people-to-live-in-the-eye-of).

Answer (score 51):

> The [eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)) is a region of mostly calm weather at the center of strong tropical cyclones. The eye of a storm is a roughly circular area. It is surrounded by the eyewall, a ring of towering thunderstorms where the most severe weather and highest winds occur.
>
> In strong tropical cyclones, the eye is characterized by light winds and clear skies, surrounded on all sides by a towering, symmetric eyewall.

If we assume this to be true also for an hypercane, it means that the island would be constantly into an area of calm weather, meaning no rainfall, for centuries. The island itself, lacking rainfall, would be a barren landscape, more or less like the Sahara or the Atacama desert.

Lacking trees, there would be no possibility for humans to build boats and therefore to fish, therefore on the long term human life would be simply impossible on the island.

Comment: I think the lack of rain is a great observation. But maybe possible there's underground water (springs or oasis) or glacial run-off (top of mountain continually grows ice from water vapor, glacier expands "downslope," then melts in lower altitudes/warmer temps. Still, upvote.

Comment: @Xplodotron, any humidity reaching the air would be lifted up by the circulation and would precipitate elsewhere. Look at the Tropics.

Comment: I think you're right. Glaciers form by snow fall, not freezing dew. Ok. But still, underground water, eh?

Comment: Or it might be more Hollywood to have a crazy but courageous group of water gatherers sail close to the edge of the eye where the storm(s) is and gather just enough rainfall to avoid sinking.

Comment: @Xplodotron That's actually hilarious and awesome. I love it

Comment: @Xplodotron or they build rainwater collectors floating out on the sea and have someone responsible for reeling them in/out to a safe distance (plot hook: one about to have a shift gets majorly inconvenienced). Or some super-early desalination tech. Agriculture is still going to be an issue though.

Comment: @RickD If your hypercane is permanent, how life developed in the island in the first place?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Totally! And someone can put a bomb in one of them that explodes if it goes less than 50 knots... Desalination with solar stills or wick stills seems possible, even on an early communal level. Yes!

Comment: @T.Sar Aliens of an ancient ilk.

Comment: Even if there was no rainfall, there should be dew most every morning.  I think "barren" is a bit much.

Comment: From that same article: "There is, however, very little wind and rain, especially near the center." So it looks like there is some rain after all, even if it's "very little", it would be constant.

Comment: @DanielP It depends on how well-formed the eye is. For a very strong hurricane (of which this would surely be one,) the eye is pretty much completely clear of clouds and precip. Weaker hurricanes may occasionally have clouds form over the eye (or the eye disappear entirely,) especially during [eyewall replacement cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyewall_replacement_cycle).

Comment: We just need the eye position to wooble a little to put sometimes the island close enough to the eye's edge to get some rainfall. It would get some wind, too, and those woobling episodes could be rough times for inhabitants, although necessary ones.

Comment: Who says the ocean is saltwater?  It doesn't have to be.  You could just irrigate, or have some other natural process bring water up on to the land.

Comment: You don't need boats to fish, look at the Bajau people.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Duh of course! Fresh water oceans, why not!?

Comment: @Xplodotron - and if they're aliens they could be adapted to drink seawater.  There are animals on Earth adapted to drink it - seems to be a function of the kidneys.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Wow, now you're breaking ALL the rules! Have you no decency, good sir! Heck, the oceans could be liquid plastic, and the planet could be an interdimensional fold, and the aliens could be bowls of cereal...  Ok, maybe I've gone too far.

Comment: @Xplodotron This is sounding more and more like a Douglas Adams story all the time...  :)

Answer (score 19):

While the weather in the eye is calm and possible to live in, there are big sea waves from the storm. The coasts would be uninhabitable and fishing impossible. If there are major rivers, large ocean waves and swells tend to propagate upriver.

The island would need protection, such as coastal cliffs from hard rock which does not erode easily. Or perhaps very extensive coastal lagunas and mangrove forests.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes.

The eye of a terrestrial hurricane, no matter what size, is a zone of calm winds and relatively clear skies around which whirls the raging tempest.

[image]

The picture shows what it's like inside a hurricane's Eye.  Nice and calm, trees are happy, not a lot of rain or wind.

This is the accompanying video, courtesy of [Hurricane Michael](https://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2018/10/11/hurricane-michael-eyewall-storm-chaser-footage-es-vpx.cnn).

If your hypercane remains perfectly rooted over and surrounding an island, then people can live on the island in its Eye indefinitely. Winds are calm; precipitation is sparse to light. Since your storm is a magical artifact, the kataigothurge that whipped it up in the first place could allow for occasional squalls and showers within the Eye.

The limiting factors will be the usual for island life: resources & space.  The Storm itself will serve to keep them in and outsiders away, but apart from that shouldn't have much of an effect on the island itself.

Comment: what about the barometric pressure? Do you think anything with the low pressure zone would affect human settlement? I think for a larger hurricane the eye will be an unusually low pressure zone right?

Comment: Low pressure shouldn't be a problem.   It would be equivalent to some distance up a mountain,  but nothing like a vacuum.

Comment: @cmm Not even very far up a mountain. For a very, very strong hurricane, central pressure is still about 90% of normal. In the Atlantic Basin, [87% of normal is the all-time record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Wilma). This is equivalent to about 3,700-3,800 ft. (around 1,100 meters) altitude in a standard atmosphere. (By "% of normal," I mean, "% of sea level pressure in a standard atmosphere.")

Comment: @cmm To contextualize reirab's comment, that's basically the air pressure in denver at 83%.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add to the point of lacking rainfall.

I would posit that are some turbulences or the eye-wall is somewhat wandering around or splitting of rain clouds. When looking at pictures of hurricane eyes the wall is not smooth and the sky is not completely free of clouds.

So if you have a very large eye you could declare that from time to time a part of the wall tears off and brings rain to a part of the island. You could state that the midst of the island is like a desert but the nearer you get to the eye wall the more water you get, and also that the air is humid, so that while it maybe rains rarely it is enough to support life.

A fun twist would be a half-island extending beyond the wall and dangerous expeditions into the storm, and a mountain chain on that half-island siphoning a lot of water from the eye wall (Foehn effect).